# Showing without calculating the integral that: $\pi/2 \leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2} \leq \pi$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to prove without calculating the integral that:

$\pi/2 \leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2} \leq \pi$.

I have some problem, since if my function is:
$f:[0,\pi]\to R$ defined by
$f(x)=\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2}$ then $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ and since f is non-negative in this intervel then the given integral is $\geq 0$ so is it legal to use the integral monotone theorem?
I mean can i say that for every $x\in [0,\pi]$, $\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2} \leq x\sin(x)$ and $\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2}\geq x\sin(x)/2$ ?

Comment: Are asking whether those two inequalities in your last sentence are true for all $x \in [0,\pi/2]$?

Comment: Any particular reason for not wanting to simply calculate the integral? Integration by parts and a nod to symmetry shows the value is $\pi^2/4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For  $x\in [0,\pi]$, $\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2} \leq x\sin(x)$ and $\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2}\geq x\sin(x)/2$  , this is true because ,the first inequality is true because the denominator is $>1$ for all $x$ in the domain and the numerator is positive and the second because the denominator is always less than equal to $2$ for all $x$ in the domain and the numerator is always positive  .

Since $f(x)>0$ you can conclude that the inequality also holds true for their integrals from $0$ to $\pi$

And since the integral of $x\sin(x)$ from $0$ to $\pi$ is $\pi$ the first inequality in the question is true .

Comment: In the inequality we want to prove $π/2≤\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{xsin(x)}{1+cos(x)^2} ≤π$ Can we substitute any value of x in the interval? Like 0 or π ? @Vivaan Daga

Comment: I don’t understand substitute $x$ where ? @user726608

Comment: In the inequality we want to prove, the one i mentioned in the comment..

Comment: Yes because of the reason mentioned in the answer it holds for $[0,/pi]$ not only $[0,/pi/2]$ this fact is important since the integral of $xsin(x)$ from $0 $ to pi is equal to pi and since $f>0$ the inequality you want to prove immediately follows .@user726608

Comment: It seems that you proved both inequalities on the same ground. Why in the end you mention only one of them?

Comment: @user I don’t quite understand .

Comment: @user726608 the integral of $f$ on $0 $ to $\pi$ is bounded by those bounds. Not $f$ .

Comment: You write "And since...the **first** inequality in the question is true." Though the same argument holds for both inequalities. The impression is that initially you had in mind only one ("the first") inequality.

Comment: Hi @Vivaan Daga but f can be zero when $x=0 or x=\pi$ so i was asking why it is not a contradiction that : $\pi/2 \leq 0\leq \pi$ when we substitute 0 or $\pi$ in f in the inequaliy in the question.Is it because $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{xsinx}{1+cos^2x}$ is actually a certain value (number) so we cannot substitue some x it?

Comment: @user726608 yes exactly

Comment: @user726608 Does this answer answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You have some excellent answers about proving your inequality now. However, some seem to think that we cannot evaluate this integral directly. I will show that in fact this integral can be evaluated directly.

---

Firstly, we need to know the following very useful result, which can be seen by making the substitution $u=a+b-x$:
$$\int_a^bf(x)~dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)~dx$$
In our case, if $I$ is our integral, then
$$\begin{align}I&=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-x)\sin(\pi-x)}{1+\cos^2(\pi-x)}dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-x)\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx=\pi\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}-\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx\\
&=\pi\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx-I\\
\implies 2I&=\pi\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx\\
\implies I&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx
\end{align}$$
Now make the substitution $y=\cos x$, so that $\sin x~dx=-dy$. Dealing with the bounds now: when $x=\pi$, $y=-1$ and when $x=0$, $y=1$. Hence,
$$\begin{align}I&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\cos^2(x)}\sin x~dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_1^{-1}\frac{-1}{1+y^2}dy=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left[\arctan y\right]_{-1}^1=\frac{\pi}{2}(\arctan 1-\arctan(-1))\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}(2\arctan 1)=\pi\arctan 1\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi @A-Level Student nice approach! Can we show the inequality, by finding the derivative of $f$ and the stational points in the interval (if exist) ?  It is problematic since in the interval the function is increasing so 0 and $\pi$ will be its stational points! And we also know that $f\geq 0, f(0)=f(\pi)=0$..

Answer (score 1):

Those inequalities in your last sentence are both obviously true when $x=0$.

And if $0 < x \le \pi/2$ then all factors occurring in those inequalities are positive (the factor $x$, the factor $\sin(x)$, and the factor $1 + \cos(x)^2$), and so after some rearrangement those inequalities are equivalent to $1 + \cos(x)^2 \ge 1$ and $1 + \cos(x)^2 \le 2$ which together are equivalent to $0 \le \cos(x)^2 \le 1$ which is true.

Comment: Since your question has $\le$ signs --- which stands for less than OR EQUAL TO --- there is no problem substituting $x=0$.

Comment: But we also have $\geq$ so $0 \geq \pi/2$..i mean substituting in the inequality we want to show

Comment: I do not see $0 \ge \pi/2$ occurring anywhere in your post. Where do you see it occurring?

Comment: In the inequality we want to prove $\pi/2 \leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2} \leq \pi$ Can we substitute any value of x in the interval? Like 0 or $\pi$ ?

Comment: @LeeMosher the inequalities also hold for $0<x<\pi$  this helps because the integral of $xsinx$ from $0$ to $\pi$ is $pi$ and so the problem mentioned in the question can be answered as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-This integral is not elementary so it is not question of direct calculation. However we have
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2}\gt \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2}=\frac{\pi}{2} $$ and something similar coul be apply maybe to the majorant $\pi$. This is just a comment.

Comment: How can you say that the integral is not elementary? I am just curious.

Comment: Why do you put "$>$" sign? How do you justify this?

Comment: @Myst1cal: Many ways. First at all it does not figure in any "table" of elementary integrals. Onother way is asking about this integral in a computer calculator so you can see what "complicated" is the answer.Regards.

Comment: @Piquito, I agree that the *indefinite* integral of $x\sin x/(1+\cos^2x)$ is not elementary, but the *definite* integral is not hard to evaluate exactly with first-year calculus techniques. (See my comment below the OP.)

Comment: @user: below the integral $ x$ is a positive number which can give "problems" from $0$ to $1$ but itis compensatory from $1$ to $\pi=3.16159.....$ Actually the graph is good to prefer.

Comment: @Barry Cipra: I don't doute of what you say, not necessary to see your comment for me. You know well about maths when you say something.

Comment: @Piquito The indefinite integral can be calculated reasonably simply, see my answer.

Comment: @A-Level Student: Very nice approach. However maybe you have to take not the indefinite integral but the definite one (see at Barry Cipra's comment above).